# How to ignore white-spaces in subversive?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

How to ignore white-spaces in subversive? is it only supported by that another svn plugin?

Comment: Whitespaces where? What's "that another svn plugin"?

Comment: AFAIK the diff view is part of Eclipse itself and shared by all repository plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.akatombo.com/en/comments/ignore_whitespace_in_a_subversion_diff/), Subversion doesn't have a built-in option for this. You can, however, use an external diff program that does by doing something like this (depending on your OS and what diff software you have installed):

```
svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x -uw /path/to/file
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you mean ignore white-spaces in subversive when "svn diff" or on every commit.

For svn diff, this command can solve your problem:

```
svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style
```

For every commit, you can refer [this subversive FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#auto-props)